# Smarthost configuration to configure sSMTP to relay sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, ssmtp, smarthost

The "clear problem statement" is How to configure sSMTP to relay sendgrid as smarthost ?

The default sSMTP config is::

```
$ cat /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
root=postmaster
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=mail
#rewriteDomain=
hostname=spinoza
```

With Exim4 we can configure SMTP as a  smarthost using the following configuration (it's working)::

```
root@me:/etc/exim4# grep -E 'sendgri|smart' update-exim4.conf.conf
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'
dc_smarthost='smtp.sendgrid.net::587'
root@me:/etc/exim4#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mailhub=smtp.sendgrid.com:587
UseSTARTTLS=YES
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=login_sendgrid
AuthPass=password_sendgrid
```